# Windows 8 metro app - pop up alert with an OK button using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-8, popup

I'm writing a register screen that will pop up an error alert when the login information is not correct.

Comment: -1. Please be more specific. What have you tried? What type of app (i.e. WinForms, WPF, Metro etc)? Have you tried MessageBox class?

Comment: sorry, just rewrote my question

Comment: OK, again you have not specified your application architecture. For WinForms and WPF applications, I think you can just use the MessageBox class (as stated in answers below), but say fro example you were building your first Metro application, you would not use a MessageBox here...this would not fit with the Metro design, therefor there is likely to be another mechanism here!

Comment: Wait a sec, I see you've edited the title to say Metro app...my bad!

Comment: @activwerx sorry, I'm kind of new in this forum and so am I in Windows metro app development. I don't know which one is a good question format and which one is not, I'm just looking for a cure of my curiosity. Because sometimes when I do curious I cannot leave my computer

Comment: That's not a problem, you'll get used to it. Everyone has to start somewhere :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reading this article on adding Message Boxes to Metro based applications:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738361.aspx

Comment: explored your link and found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738361.aspx . work perfectly and as simple as I have expected. thanks!

Answer (score 17):

In one line...

```
await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Man why did they have to make this so complicated in Win 8").ShowAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

In a Windows Store app, use `new MessageDialog("My Message").ShowAsync();`  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog) for reference.

Comment: Looks like you need the Windows.UI.Popups in front

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on what specific situation are you talking about but if you want to use OK and CANCEL button on you user Interface then you can use  :

`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, Page.GetType(), "alert", "confirm('You are about to confirm')?window.location='Yes':window.location='No';", true);`

or if you want only to redirect on ok button click then You can  use :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You are about to confirm');window.location='Yes';", true);
```

**You have to add System.Web.UI namespace**

Answer (score 0):

here the full code for a button to show the messagebox:

```
private async void DisplayMessageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Welcome to Windows 8 Store Apps", "Windows 8");
     await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```